# Python - WTForm. Как установить значение SelectField из БД в шаблоне?

Tags: python, wtforms

SQLObject.py

```
class Object(SQLObject):

id

name
```

WTForm.py

```
class AForm(WTForm..):
select_name = SelectField(choices=[(i.id,i.name) for i in model.A.select()])
```

index.html

```
{% for i in objects %}
{{ form.select_name( ??? ) }} # (value=i.ID) //ничего не меняет.
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, не нужно задавать `choices`, во время создания атрибута `select_name`. Если так сделать, то в поле попадут значения из базы данных, которые были на момент запуска вашего Flask приложения. То есть если, в будущем в базе появятся другие кортежи или наоборот - удалятся, ваше поле выбора будет содержать те старые значения, которые были на момент запуска приложения. Что бы избежать этого, получение данных из БД нужно вынести в отдельный метод, и вызывать его после создания объекта формы, например:

WTForm.py

```
class AForm(WTForm..):
    select_name = SelectField(choices=[])

    def set_choices(self):
        self.select_name.choices = [(i.id,i.name) for i in model.A.select()]
```

Файл, где вы создаете объект формы и генерите шаблон:

```
form = AForm()
form.set_choices()
```

Ну и возвращаясь к вашему вопросу, через шаблон так сделать не получится, либо не используйте WTForms в данном случае, а просто выводите поля с помощью HTML, либо генерируйте динамически для каждого поля атрибут в классе(но так я делать не советую). И вообще, как вы собрались обрабатывать эту форму на стороне сервера? Вы определили класс WTForms с одним полем `select_name`, а в итоге на странице их будет несколько, с одним именем и одним идентификатором. Не думаю что это правильное решение.